# Calculate every row in a pandas dataframe with a value specific to that row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a fairly big dataframe with around 20 columns containing floats, and one column with a factor.

| index | col1 | col2 | factor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row1 | 5.2 | 10.5 | 1.01 |
| row2 | 92.61 | 141.7 | 1.3 |
| row3 | 2.75 | 205.56 | 1.9 |

I want to multiply every value in each row with the factor for that row.

How can I do this fairly fast?

I have considered df.iterrows() to loop and try to multiply all values with row['Factor'], but this has not been successful.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For in place modification, you could use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to select the columns, [`mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) to perform the multiplication, and [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) to update the DataFrame with the new values:

```
df.update(df.filter(like='col').mul(df['factor'], axis=0))
```

*NB. with `update`, the modification is **in place**, there is no output, `df` is modified directly.*

resulting `df`:

```
  index     col1     col2  factor
0  row1    5.252   10.605    1.01
1  row2  120.393  184.210    1.30
2  row3    5.225  390.564    1.90
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) for columns names for multiple by column with [`DataFrame.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html):

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['factor'])
df[cols] = df[cols].mul(df['factor'], axis=0)
print (df)
         col1     col2  factor
row1    5.252   10.605    1.01
row2  120.393  184.210    1.30
row3    5.225  390.564    1.90
```